# Compare and merge objects in List

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a class:

```
class CustomDetail{
 String version;
 List<String> details;
}
```

And in result of some method I have the list of CustomDetail like

```
List<CustomDetails> resultList 
resultList.get(0) => CustomDetail("V1", {"123"})
resultList.get(1) => CustomDetail("V1", {"456"})
...
resultList.get(9) => CustomDetail("B", {"atr"})
resultList.get(10) => CustomDetail("B", {"atr1"})
resultList.get(11) => CustomDetail("B", {"atr3"})
```

CustomDetails in this list may contain same vers fild.

and i need to merge of this objects like:

```
List<CustomDetails> newList = ...
newList.get(0)=> CustomDetail("V1", {"123", "456"})
newList.get(1)=> CustomDetail("B", {"atr", "atr1", "atr3"})
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score -1):

First implement `equals` and `hashCode` on your `CustomDetail`. In all likelihood your IDE has a shortcut to do  generate the necessary code.

Then create a `Set` (i.e. `HashSet`) and add both lists to it. As the set cannot contain duplicate entries you end up with a collection only containing unique members. If you need to you can then create a `List` from your `Set`.